# Angular & Ionic - Filter boolean

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to get a boolean from this:

```
var category_data = $filter('filter')(data, {id: id}, true)[0]['subs'];
```

But it does not give me true or false. I'm using it here:

```
if(!category_data) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return category_data;
  }
```

What i'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you have something like this:

```
if(!category_data) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return category_data;
  }
```

You can always replace it with:

```
return !!category_data;
```

and get a boolean.

---

However, you didn't provide enough info about the filter, so it's going to be hard to help if the problem you're facing is in there.

Comment: The filter actually looks up for a id on an array. I just need if it finds something, it just returns what it found, or if doesnt find anything, return false.

Comment: In that case the line I gave you will return true when the filter has found something and false when it hasn't.

Comment: Still doestn working. Returns me this: ypeError: Cannot read property 'subs' of undefined.

Comment: Then the error is in your first line. You need to check if `$filter('filter')(data, {id: id}, true)[0]` exists first, before looking for its `subs` property.

Comment: I downvoted because boolean casting doesn't answer the question, nor does saying 'you didn't provide enough information'. I didn't think it was a controversial downvote, but maybe I'm wrong. Edit: I would update your answer with your comment which has the actual answer.

Comment: @azium, I might've misunderstood where exactly the problem was (I understood OP wanted a boolean instead of the full object), but that's why I described which part I (correctly) answered. If he had shown the error message from the comments, it would've been pretty much straghtforward.

Comment: @Shomz Even if the question was only "how do I get a boolean value from this?", boolean casting is an answer, but I don't think it's a good one. I would say only if the question is "what is a shorthand for finding the truthiness of non-boolean values"